# Yii hosted on amazon mkdir(): No space left on device

Tags: php, yii, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I tried to delete the sub folders on assets folder where there is lib folder including some other files inside lib folder too as well as phpinfo.php also.

After deleting all the files inside assets folder, It gives php warning

```
mkdir(): No space left on device
```

on file /var/www/framework/utils/CFileHelper.php(287)

```
@param array $options newDirMode element used, must contain access bitmask.
276      * @param boolean $recursive
277      * @return boolean result of mkdir
278      * @see mkdir
279      */
280     private static function mkdir($dst,array $options,$recursive)
281     {
282         $prevDir=dirname($dst);
283         if($recursive && !is_dir($dst) && !is_dir($prevDir))
284             self::mkdir(dirname($dst),$options,true);
285 
286         $mode=isset($options['newDirMode']) ? $options['newDirMode'] : 0777;
287         $res=mkdir($dst, $mode);
288         chmod($dst,$mode);
289         return $res;
290     }
291 }
```

I don't know if it is the disk space problem on amazon ec2.

Can anyone please point out the cause of the error.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Well, it seems that you have no space. do you know how many space you have? if yes, do `var_dump(system('du -sh /www'))` to see how many space you used

Comment: We're using ubuntu server on amazon ec2 and by doing df -h It showed total of 7.8 gb

Comment: Can you post the full output of `df- h` ?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the support.
Now the problem has been fixed.
After linking to ebs volume this is the output.    

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/xvdg       7.8G  6.6G  833M  89% /
    none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    udev            285M   12K  285M   1% /dev
    tmpfs            59M  196K   59M   1% /run
    none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    none            295M     0  295M   0% /run/shm
    none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
    /dev/xvdf        30G   44M   28G   1% /mnt/ebs-volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your instance EBS based?  Do you have your app on the EBS vol?   As above, post the full results of:

> df -h

and

> lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL

Comment: Thank you for your the support. Now the problem has been somehow been fixed. 
After linking to ebs volume this is the output. Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on /dev/xvdg 7.8G 6.6G 833M 89% / none 4.0K 0 4.0K 0% /sys/fs/cgroup udev 285M 12K 285M 1% /dev tmpfs 59M 196K 59M 1% /run none 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock none 295M 0 295M 0% /run/shm none 100M 0 100M 0% /run/user /dev/xvdf 30G 44M 28G 1% /mnt/ebs-volume –